# check if array1 contains any element from array2, using loadash or some native method?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I know i can write custom loop that takes `array1` and for each element do `indexOf` to another array.

But I'm trying to make a game. And i can see myself running into lots of cases where i'd be forced to write same code over and over. Therefore, i think using some utility library is a good idea. Right now my mind is set on `lodash`. However, I've to learn it first.

So how do i compare two arrays easily, and return true if any element matches any element in another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no lodash method that compares two arrays and returns a boolean if there are any duplicates between the two arrays.  There is [`_.intersection()`](https://lodash.com/docs#intersection), but that returns an array of all the duplicates, and thus is not as efficient as it could be.

So, just write a simple function to do it.  I'd call it `containsAny()`:

### es5

```
function containsAny(a, b) {
    return a.some(function(el) {
        return b.indexOf(el) > -1;
    });
}
```

### es4

Since `Array.prototype.some()` and `Array.prototype.indexOf()` are both new to JavaScript as of version 5, here is some vanilla javascript that will work in ancient browsers without shims:

```
function containsAny(a, b) {
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (contains(b, el)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
function contains(a, el) {
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i] === el) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

### lodash

The lodash version really isn't any simpler than the vanilla js version, though it may be faster in some browsers.

```
function containsAny(a, b) {
    return _.some(a, function(el) {
        return _.contains(b, el);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, the most straight forward method in comparing two arrays is a double for-loop, giving you a run-time of about O(n^2). Personally i'm rusty on javascript, but this seems more of an algorithmic issue.

To gain better efficiency, you may want to use data structures which are more aptly suited to quick searches such as a hash table (this is assuming you just want to know if the item exists in the list at all).

In this situation, as you add/delete items to array2, you also add/delete these items in the hashtable. When you would like to know if array1 contains any items from array2, you would use a single for-loop to iterate through all the items in array1 and run the element through the hash-tables search function, which I believe only has a runtime of O(1). This would make it more efficient, but require more memory. This should leave your whole algorithm with a runtime of about O(n).

--

Hash tables work by basically running your input through an algorithm that provides it a value. Your input is then stored at the index of this value. To search if this element exists, you simply run it through the same hashing algorithm and check the location of the output. The search function itself should return a boolean, which you can then exit your search function (if true).

More on HashTables:     http://www.cs.uregina.ca/Links/class-info/210/Hash/

Comment: this gives me something to think about even though im using array, i dont feel like for just performance i should use hash table, or object in js speak.

Comment: but yea when i need quick lookup i do this with object `table['keyname'] != undefined`